# Javascript insertBefore iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

For reasons I won't go into, I need to use an iframe in a page (I know they are outdated etc etc). I also need to use javascript to insert a link before the iframe.

According to W3 schools this should be easy:

```
var newItem = document.createElement("LI");       // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");  // Create a text node
newItem.appendChild(textnode);                    // Append the text to <li>

var list = document.getElementById("myList");    // Get the <ul> element to insert a new node
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);  // Insert <li> before the first child of <ul>
```

However, this seems to work with every html element except an iframe?

Can anyone explain how to do it or at least why it doesn't work with iframes.

Comment: *"However, this seems to work with every html element except an iframe?"* What makes you think it doesn't work with iframes? Rather than quoting the code that *does* work, when asking for help, quote the code you tried that *didn't* work. `insertBefore` works just fine with `iframes`, so the problem lies in code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
iframeElement.parentNode.insertBefore(insertedNode, iframeElement);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`insertBefore` suddenly didn't work before an `iframe` using Chrome version 104. The `iframe` was replaced. I restarted Chrome, and everything worked again.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a link before IFRAME.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9a668dz/

```
$('<a href=#>a link</a>').insertBefore('iframe')
```

I don't see any iframe in your code

**Or if you prefer pure Javascript:**

```
var a=document.createElement('a')
a.innerHTML='hello world'
a.href='#'

document.body.insertBefore(a,document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qd4ppmga/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does appear to work in the jsfiddle, but still not working in my site. Must be an issue with code elsewhere on the page. I will investigate...